# Sort list of dictionaries based on the order given by another list

Tags: python, sorting

There are a lot of [similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20sort%20list%20of%20dicts%20based%20on%20another%20list%20site:stackoverflow.com) on Stack Overflow but not exactly this one.

I need to sort a list of dictionaries based on the values of another list but (unlike all the other questions I found) the second list just gives the order, is not an element of the dictionary.

Let's say I have these lists

```
a = [{"a": 5}, {"b": 5}, {"j": {}}, {123: "z"}]
b = [8, 4, 4, 3]
```

Where `b` does not contain values of the dictionaries in the list, but gives the order (ascending) to use to sort `a`, therefore I want the output to be:

```
[{123: "z"}, {"b": 5}, {"j": {}}, {"a": 5}]
```

I tried `sorted(zip(b, a)` but this gives an error probably because when it finds a tie it tries to sort on the second list

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[497], line 1
----> 1 sorted(zip(b, a))

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'
```

In case of ties it's fine to leave the original order

Comment: How does `[8,4,4,3]` correspond to that desired output?

Comment: It seems like you want to sort one list based on the order of another list, and your question actually has nothing to do with dictionaries, correct?

Comment: @Joe It does in the sense that with for example strings instead of dict's it wouldn't crash.

Comment: @Joe But if they remove "of dicts" from their Google search, they'll probably get the linked original as the first result (it is for me, even in an anonymous window).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the second list, and then sort the first list based on the result

```
sort_b_indexes = sorted(range(len(b)),key=lambda x:b[x])
a = [a[i] for i in sort_b_indexes]
```